# Why Object.clone() is able to "see" fields defined in subclasses?

Tags: java

I was wandering how can Object.Clone() access field fields that are actually defined in the subclasses, and not the actual implementation of this feature.

What is bothering me is that I cannot see the logic to allow base class (even if it is "special") to access the fields defined in the subclasses - doesn't this breaks whole object inheritance concept?

Consider this:

```
class Test implements Cloneable
{
    private String test_field;

    public Test()
    {
    }

    public Test clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
       return (Test)super.clone();
    }
}
```

Here, calling `Test.clone()` will copy the `test_field` also. Things are even getting weirder for me when it comes to the situation where `Test` is declared as an abstract class - calling `clone()` will allow me (in some way) to get the instance of the abstract class.

Comment: Did you look at the implementation of `clone()` in the JDK source? That would certainly show you how it's done.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I am not actually interested in the JDK's implementation - it is clear for me that there are dozens of ways to implement this. I was asking about the whole 'inheritance' thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326801/643483

The short answer to your question is yes, it is problematic to have the clone method on the `Object` class. According to Josh Bloch (via above link), it would have been better for the clone method to be defined on the `Cloneable` interface.